# Как написать onClicklistener для пульта Android Box?

Tags: java, android

Приветствую ! Как написать onClicklistener для пульта Android Box ? Или может у кого то есть пошаговая инструкция ?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

[Creating TV Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html)

[UI Patterns for TV](https://developer.android.com/design/tv/patterns.html)

просто создаешь кнопку и сетаешь на него OnClickListener

Comment: Прошу прощения, но очень хорошо представляю себе этот процесс. Как потом эту XML кнопку прицепить к кнопке пульта ?

Comment: я думал вы про приложение на адроид, которое выполняет роль пульта.

Comment: тогда вопрос не туда вы задали по моему

Comment: А где порекомендуете задать ?

Comment: Некоторые кнопки пульта ( Android Box ) функционируют, но не посылают KeyEvent ( Android Studio ). Как поставить на них dispatchKeyEvent если я от них не получаю KeyEvent ?